# Parsing external torrent informations

Tags: codeigniter, bittorrent, tracker

I'm build a a BitTorrent tracker with CodeIgniter, and i'm use Torrent RW class for parsing .torrent files (info hash, read/write tracker url, etc.).

I would like to run external torrents, and i need help: how to parse external torrent stats -> seeders-, leechers number.

Please, help me, and sorry for my bad english.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself the time and use an existing open php torrent tracker (or better yet, convert it over to CodeIgniter and open source it to contribute back!).

- [RivetTracker](http://www.rivetcode.com/software/rivettracker/)
- [PHPBTTracker+](http://phpbttrkplus.sourceforge.net/)
- [TBDEV.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tbdevnet/)

Most are based on the original [PHPBTTracker](http://dehacked.2y.net/BT/) by DeHackEd.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to look up the PHP required to do this and then think about implementing it in Codeigniter.

The Torrent RW class will read the torrent but you will need to somehow connect to the torrent and its seeds and leechers in order to get this information.

Check out:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tbdevnet/